I need to create the outline of a three-dimensional figure from many points in ArcGIS Pro
I have thousands of points that are made in underground storage
Is it possible to somehow make an outline of this figure in ArcGIS Pro?
I was only able to create vertical, horizontal, and diagonal lines.



I tried to use minimum bounding volume tool CONCAVE_HULL type
But this tool connects the dots inaccurate, missing some convexity.
